# SyntaxError: no visibility specified. Remix

Tags: remix

Going through some tutorials on ethreum, and got stuck here. The code seems ok for me. I tried to add the `public/private`  as the error says, then i got another error like:

```
parsererror function variable struct or modifier declaration expected
```

Who could help me out ?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract MyFirstContract{
    string private name;
    uint private age;

    function setName(string newName){
        name = newName;
    }

   function getName()returns (string){
        return name;
    }

    function setAge(uint newAge){
        age = newAge;
    }

    function getAge()returns (uint){
        return age;
    }
}
```

[image: errors]
[image: errors]

**EDIT:**
WHo could siply explain why this code doesn't display the name ? the function getName should've returned "jack"-string, but its blank. Also i'm using Java Script Environment 
[image: edited]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Solidity v0.5.0 breaking changes [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html#explicitness-requirements):

> Explicit function visibility is now mandatory. Add public to every
> function and constructor, and external to every fallback or interface
> function that does not specify its visibility already.

Your functions are missing visible specifier. Regarding the data location, it says:

> Explicit data location for all variables of struct, array or mapping
> types is now mandatory. This is also applied to function parameters
> and return variables.

When they mention `array`, it also applies on `bytes` ans `string`. Make the related changes and errors will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

Before 0.5.0, solidity by default sets formal parameters to Memory. Now in 0.5.0, You need to mention if its [memory or storage variable](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html#semantic-and-syntactic-changes).

Heres solution of your code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract MyFirstContract{
    string private name;
    uint private age;

    function setName(string memory newName)
    public {
       name = newName;
    }

   function getName()
   view
   public
   returns (string memory) {
        return name;
    }

    function setAge(uint newAge)
    public {
        age = newAge;
    }

    function getAge()
    view
    public
    returns (uint) {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Comment: heres second point about changes in [Solidity Formal Parameters](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html#explicitness-requirements).

Comment: Do you know why my code,(also your code) doesn't displays the name in getName() function. ?? i've edited the question and posted the screenshot up there .

Comment: you must Execute/Transact function setName with parameters in *double quotes*, it should be "jack". Then call getName().